# Can we find and replace with a variable in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, replace, dataset

I have a dataset where some numbers are too big to be int values (>2147483647), when there are above there are written as  `"price_amount" : { "$numberLong" : "3900000000" }`, but i've changed datatypes so I can now use 64 bytes int.

But is there a way to find all the `{ "$numberLong" : "x" }`and replace by `x` ?

I was about to do it with an external script but I thought it might be possible with the find & replace tool.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: You can use a regular expression to search by and replace with a reference to the matched value (if relevant). But I'm not sure what you want the replacement to be - can you give an example?

Comment: In the example I give, I would replace "price_amount" : { "$numberLong" : "3900000000" } by "price_amount" : 3900000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex Find Replace:

Find: `\{ "\$numberLong" : "(\d+)" \}`

Replace: `$1`

Comment: very good, parenthesis () around \d+represent that it is saved in the variable $1